# How to add different values of string resource for different flavors?

Tags: android, facebook

I'm an iOS developer who is trying to make some small changes on android side but with no clue of how to achieve them. My goal is to implement Facebook SDK inside the app, official documentation says:

> In /app/res/values/strings.xml add new string element:

`<string name="facebook_app_id">Facebook App ID</string>`

> Then add in AndroidManifest.xml file new meta-data like below:

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" ...>
    ...
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
    ...
</application>
```

All is understood but my problem is that I have few product flavors based on which I build at the end stand alone apps, for each I have different `Facebook App ID`. I would appreciate any kind of help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways. But as you already define multiple flavour in `build.gradle` in app level then you can define the string over there like this

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        flavour1 {
            buildConfigField "String", "facebook_app_id", "\"first facebook id 1\""

        }

        flavour2 {
            buildConfigField "String", "facebook_app_id", "\"first facebook id 2\""
        }
    }
}
```

It automatically initialise the facebook_app_id to the build when you are creating the build of the flavour.

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 2):

You can create multiple build types or product flavors inside the app-level build.gradle file and then define different strings for each build variant like this

```
   buildTypes {

    prod{
        resValue "string", "facebook_app_id", "your app id"
    }

    dev {
        resValue "string", "facebook_app_id", "your app id"
         }
}
```

Now you can access this string inside manifest

```
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
```

Comment: It throws => AAPT: error: resource string/some_key (aka com.app.dev:string/some_key) not found.

Answer (score 1):

**In build.gradle :**

```
productFlavors {
        appDev {
            applicationId 'com.android.dev'
        }

        appTest {
            applicationId 'com.android.test'
        }
}
flavorDimensions "default"
```

**Inside src folder:**
    
 create folder with flavors name

```
-src
    -appDev(folder)
        -java(folder)
        -res(folder)
         -values(folder)

    -appTest(folder)
        -java(folder)
        -res(folder)
         -values(folder)
```

inside values folder you can create strings.xml each folder act as different flavor

Answer (score -2):

you need to pass your facebook app_id in the string files.

```
<string name="facebook_app_id">35166120881***</string>
<string name="fb_login_protocol_scheme">fb35166120881****</string>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
       ...

    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
                android:configChanges=
                    "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
                android:label="@string/app_name" />
            <activity
                android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
                android:exported="true">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                    <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        ...

    </application>
```

Important this

```
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
```